# Importing XLS/CSV to Parse.com BaaS with Array and Dictionary data

Tags: objective-c, json, csv, xls, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as my BaaS and I am using the 'Import' function to create data tables from my existing XLS/CSV files.

This works OK when the cells in the excel spreadsheet are basic object types (Numbers, Strings, Booleans) but now I am wanting to import Array and Dictionary objects.

I know that the Parse import does not currently support this, I am wondering if anyone has developed a workaround?

I saw one posted converted their CSV file to a JSON file, but they did not share how they did this. I know also REST API is an option but I have never used this API and would prefer not to go down that path right now if it can be avoided.

Cheers